# Worry about Youtube video development permissions

Tags: video, youtube, microsoft-metro

I am planning to write a Metro app using js/html that can play YouTube videos. I reference the [YouTube iframe API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) but several limits(such as there is not 'full screen' button on the iframe-embed player) make me hard to continue with YouTube iframe API. 
Now I think of another way. That is:

firstly, request to YouTube with: `http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=[id]`, the server will response with a long string;

secondly, parse the string and get a url that can download the video directly;

third, create a video tag and set the src with above url.

finally, I can custom a player all by myself.

The method works well now. But I worry about that this way violates YouTube's Permission. Does anybody know about official permission about use YouTube video in my own app? Or where can I find some relative document? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I'd say you should contact YouTube, there's a [Help link](http://support.google.com/youtube/?hl=en-US) on their Developer's page.  YouTube is really the only entity that can give you "official permission".

That said, the [Terms of Service](http://www.youtube.com/t/terms) includes the following note:

> ```
> C.  You agree not to access Content through any technology or means other than the
>     video playback pages of the Service itself, the Embeddable Player, or other
>     explicitly authorized means YouTube may designate.
> ```